# How can i convert my JPEG files into editable format?

Tags: conversion, documents

I have some JPEG files which contain text, but I want to edit some information on it.
So I want to convert them in DOC format. How can I do this without downloading any software.

Comment: This *does* relate to computer software...

Answer (score 2):

JPEG files contain raster images (pixel data). This includes text (i.e. text is not stored as text but as pixels).

This means that in order to convert them to text (or MS Word format) you need to use OCR software. There are many such online services, e.g. see http://www.onlineocr.net/ (first google hit).

Answer (score 0):

Tesseract OCR is something I have used in the past. It worked pretty well for some things but for others it outright failed. ymmv.

http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/

Comment: I think this is what the new Google Docs facility to scan for text in PDF documents is based on, if you wanted a really long round trip you could convert the JPEG to PDF and then upload it to Google Docs!

Waits for the downvote due to this being a stupid comment...

Comment: @Richard - You can't downvote comments.

Comment: @Richard, interesting. Might be true considering google developed Tesseract.