# Convert JPEG files to a text format like RTF (with best quality)

Tags: jpeg, image-conversion, rtf

I have a JPEG files that contains only text on them, but I now want to correct some of the text, and some pictures. So I want to convert it to RTF, is this possible? I want the best quality after I convert it.

Comment: I'm confused. Also, what does this have to do with programming?

Comment: RTF isn't an image format. Are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i convert my JPEG files into editable format?](http://superuser.com/questions/162910/how-can-i-convert-my-jpeg-files-into-editable-format)

Answer (score 6):

What you really want to do is OCR (optical character recognition) the image to extract the text. You can then work with that text as a text document.

To be completely honest, it'll be easier to do this the human way. Open a new RTF document in WordPad or whatnot and type the text in the image.

If you really don't want to do this, you could try this tool: http://www.free-ocr.com/

Answer (score 3):

As you've been told before on Stackoverflow.com (a few times, looking at your history), JPEG is an *image* format.  This means the text is stored as an *image*.

Images can only be edited as a set of pixels, not as text.

It is a picture of the text.

Converting it into an RTF file will not make it a text file.

Making it an RTF will not make it easier to edit.

It will still be an image.

Answer (score 1):

The OCR is the correct and standard approach.
Another option (only if you are running at least on Windows Vista with office 2007) is to convert you image into an XPS document. After that you can edit text with word and convert you XPS document in other format.

XP Converter (*edit: this link was reported as possibly dangerous, please find another one*)
[XPS Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_XML_Paper_Specification)

Comment: If you have Vista or 7, you'll have XPS converter as one of printers. Just print the jpg and you'll get XPS file. No need for external converters.

Comment: Your previous link has been edited out, as a potentially dangerous location. Please provide another link for what you describe.